# Can I create a SAS url for Azure File storage (i.e. not Blobs)

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

Using windows azure blob storage and providing access via a url with a [Shared Access Signature](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/) is all normal and great. Can I do the same using files stored using the newer Azure File Storage?

The [Get Blob REST api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179440.aspx) says you can use a Shared Access Signature, <strike>but the [Get File REST API docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194274.aspx) don't. So I'm guessing not</strike>.

If it's not possible, what's the suggested approach to give temporary access to someone? Create a copy as a blob and use SAS for that, or just don't use File Storage for this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest WindowsAzure.Storage Version 5.0.0 has API to create SAS for Azure File Share.

Example (taken from [Tool or usage example to generate and view SAS (Shared Access Signatures) of both Azure Block Blob and Azure File Share](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32043776/1353412)):

```
static void FileShareSas(){
    var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
    var fileClient = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
    var share = fileClient.GetShareReference("share");
    var sasToken = share.GetSharedAccessSignature(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.SharedAccessFilePolicy(){
            Permissions = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.SharedAccessFilePermissions.List,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1))
        });
}
```

Feel free to check out this free tool as well:
EverDir.com

Answer (score 3):

Currently it is not possible to create a Shared Access Signature for Azure File Service.

> If it's not possible, what's the suggested approach to give temporary
>   access to someone? Create a copy as a blob and use SAS for that, or
>   just don't use File Storage for this scenario?

I would say, currently this is the best approach to do so. Other option would be to proxy your file service storage with your application.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas if this is planned to be added in future?

Comment: I would think that they will be adding this feature to make SAS functionality available across the board.

Comment: It looks like this has been added now? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx

Comment: Still the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

I guess my answer is too late, but maybe someone else is looking for the same topic.
I had the same problem and found info only about "blobs", but after making a little research I could create this method in C# that returns the SAS url

**First install the AzureStorage library to your project from the NuGet Management Tool**

```
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
```

And here you have the code

```
public string GetFromUrl(string folder, string fileName)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=yourStorageAcountName;AccountKey=yourKey");
    CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

    Uri myUri = new Uri("https://yourAcount.file.core.windows.net/yourDirectory/"+ folder);
    CloudFileDirectory directory = new CloudFileDirectory(myUri, storageAccount.Credentials);

    var result = GetFileSasUri(directory, fileName);
    return result;
}

static string GetFileSasUri(CloudFileDirectory container, string fileName)
{
    CloudFile file = container.GetFileReference(fileName);
    SharedAccessFilePolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessFilePolicy();
    sasConstraints.SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5);
    sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24);
    sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read | SharedAccessFilePermissions.Write;
    string sasBlobToken = file.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);
    SharedAccessFilePolicy sharedPolicy = new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
        Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Write | SharedAccessFilePermissions.List | SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read
    };


    return file.Uri + sasBlobToken;
}
```

In this example the "Folder" parameter could be empty or should end with "/".
The file name, must have its extention (e.g audio.mp3)
Please notice that the link has an expiry date, but you can add hours, days, and even years for this ;)

Hope it could help you

Comment: Make sure your API version is 5 or above or `SharedAccessFilePolicy` will be undefined.